# zeromq c identification client

Tags: c++, zeromq

i worked in visual studio 2015 in win7 x64.

i try to find specific client by zmq_identity. but
was not work.

### codes

### server

```
void *context = zmq_ctx_new();
//  Socket to talk to clients
zmq::socket_t* responder = (zmq::socket_t*)zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_REP);
zmq_setsockopt(responder, ZMQ_IDENTITY, "hell", 4);
zmq_connect(responder, "tcp://localhost:5560");

while (1) {
    //  Wait for next request from client
    char buf[512];
    zmq_recv(responder, buf, 512, ZMQ_RCVMORE);
    zmq_recv(responder, buf, 512,0);
    sleep(1);
    zmq_send(responder, "B", 1, ZMQ_SNDMORE);
    zmq_send(responder, "worldB",5, 0);
}
zmq_close(responder);
zmq_ctx_destroy(context);
return 0;
```

---

### client

```
void *context = zmq_ctx_new();

//  Socket to talk to server
void *requester = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_REQ);
zmq_setsockopt(requester, ZMQ_IDENTITY, "A", 1);
zmq_connect(requester, "tcp://localhost:5506");

int request_nbr;

for (request_nbr = 0; request_nbr < 5; request_nbr++) 
{
    char buf[512];
    zmq_send(requester, "Hello", 5, 0);
    std::cout << "IN RECV" << std::endl;

    int recvc = zmq_recv(requester, buf, 512, ZMQ_RCVMORE);
    printf("Received reply %d [%s]\n", recvc, buf);

    char buf2[512];
     recvc = zmq_recv(requester, buf2, 512, 0);
    printf("Received reply %d [%s]\n", recvc, buf2);
}
```

---

### broker

```
//  Prepare our context and sockets
void *context = zmq_ctx_new();
void *frontend = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_ROUTER);
void *backend = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_DEALER);
zmq_bind(frontend, "tcp://*:5506");
zmq_bind(backend, "tcp://*:5560");


zmq_proxy(frontend, backend,NULL);
```

---

if you run this, you can see the client get identifier B's message;

i wanna know how to set client identification using zmq identity.

Comment: thanks to comment. it's useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do connect using a `REP` socket, you don't see the identity. It is stripped out by the socket.

You should try to connect using a `DEALER` socket, to see the identity frame.